# iOS UI Testing : Failure getting list of active applications: AX error -25205

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I am still learning how to use UI Testing properly.

I login in the background and later, I show result in my news feed. Then, I tap on more button. When there is web service, it look like I can't get result from my api. It always fail like this and data from my api are not shown also. How shall I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue while using simulator. I tried running test case on device and it is working fine. So Run on actual device and see if error appears.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `sleep()` in your tests. Instead, use the native APIs to wait for elements to exist. For example, you can wait until the "Contests" text appears with the following:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *moreButton = app.tabBars.buttons[@"More"];

XCUIElement *contestsText = app.staticTexts[@"Contests"];
NSPredicate *exists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exists == YES"];
[self expectationForPredicate:exists evaluatedWithObject:contestsText handler:nil];

[moreButton tap];

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0f handler:nil];
XCTAssert(contestsText.exists);
```

This example comes from my [UI Testing Cheat Sheet](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-wait-for-an-element-to-appear). If you are just getting started with UI Testing I recommend you check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the simulator resolved the issue for me. It can be done by `Simulator` - `Reset Content and Settings...` from the main menu of the simulator.

To use with CI systems, these commands might help:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iOS Simulator" to quit'
osascript -e 'tell application "Simulator" to quit'
xcrun simctl erase all
```