# (UI Testing with Swift) Failure getting list of active applications: AX error -25205

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Our tests were working perfectly, but for no apparent reason (checked the commits), the UI tests simply stopped to work in the simulator (haven't tested on a device yet). Every time it needs to perform an action on an UI component (like `tap()` or `typeText("string here")`) we get the error in the title, `Failure getting list of active applications: AX error -25205`.

Here is the log from the point everything goes wrong:

```
    t =    13.57s             Find: Elements matching predicate '"TextFieldUsuario" IN identifiers'
    t =    13.74s             Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failure getting list of active applications: AX error -25205
/Users/desenvolvimento/projetos/Mobile-iOS/Mobile-iOSUITests/SupportUITests.swift:45: error: -[Mobile_iOSUITests.LoginViewControllerUITest testLoginComSucesso] : UI Testing Failure - Failure getting list of active applications: AX error -25205
2016-07-15 09:46:42.722 XCTRunner[22227:716756] -[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8728d66170
    t =    13.74s             Tear Down
/Users/desenvolvimento/projetos/Mobile-iOS/Mobile-iOSUITests/SupportUITests.swift:45: error: -[Mobile_iOSUITests.LoginViewControllerUITest testLoginComSucesso] : failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8728d66170"
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102552d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101fc6deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010255bd3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024a1cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024a18a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   XCTest                              0x0000000101a70fcb -[XCAXClient_iOS activeApplications] + 438
    6   XCTest                              0x0000000101a71eb9 -[XCAXClient_iOS interruptingUIElementAffectingSnapshot:] + 102
    7   XCTest                              0x0000000101a92ad9 -[XCUIElementQuery matchingSnapshotsHandleUIInterruption:withError:] + 180
    8   XCTest                              0x0000000101a83d74 __43-[XCUIElement resolveHandleUIInterruption:]_block_invoke + 238
    9   XCTest                              0x0000000101a63629 -[XCTestCase startActivityWithTitle:block:] + 350
    10  XCTest                              0x0000000101a83c79 -[XCUIElement resolveHandleUIInterruption:] + 140
    11  XCTest                              0x0000000101aa3d81 __63-[XCUIElement(XCUIElementEventSynthesis) _dispatchEvent:block:]_block_invoke + 82
    12  XCTest                              0x0000000101a63629 -[XCTestCase startActivityWithTitle:block:] + 350
    13  XCTest                              0x0000000101aa3d20 -[XCUIElement(XCUIElementEventSynthesis) _dispatchEvent:block:] + 405
    14  XCTest                              0x0000000101aa4ea7 -[XCUIElement(XCUIElementEventSynthesis) tap] + 121
    15  Mobile-iOSUITests                   0x0000000110d7cfca _TFC17Mobile_iOSUITests14SupportUITests13executarLoginfTCSo15XCUIApplication5loginSS5senhaSS_T_ + 1210
    16  Mobile-iOSUITests                   0x0000000110d7d653 _TFC17Mobile_iOSUITests14SupportUITests32performarLoginValidoComAplicacaofCSo15XCUIApplicationT_ + 627
    17  Mobile-iOSUITests                   0x0000000110d77d3a _TFC17Mobile_iOSUITests25LoginViewControllerUITest19testLoginComSucessofT_T_ + 138
    18  Mobile-iOSUITests                   0x0000000110d77d82 _TToFC17Mobile_iOSUITests25LoginViewControllerUITest19testLoginComSucessofT_T_ + 34
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010243b5cc __invoking___ + 140
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010243b41e -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
    21  XCTest                              0x0000000101a5fef3 __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke_2 + 362
    22  XCTest                              0x0000000101a94613 -[XCTestContext performInScope:] + 190
    23  XCTest                              0x0000000101a5fd78 -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 169
    24  XCTest                              0x0000000101a603a2 -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 459
    25  XCTest                              0x0000000101a5dcf7 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 396
    26  XCTest                              0x0000000101a5dcf7 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 396
    27  XCTest                              0x0000000101a4ab10 __25-[XCTestDriver _runSuite]_block_invoke + 51
    28  XCTest                              0x0000000101a6bb4c -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 640
    29  XCTest                              0x0000000101a4aa55 -[XCTestDriver _runSuite] + 453
    30  XCTest                              0x0000000101a4b7d1 -[XCTestDriver _checkForTestManager] + 259
    31  XCTest                              0x0000000101a95a9a _XCTestMain + 628
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024782ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010246df75 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010246d6d2 __CFRunLoopRun + 850
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010246d0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010460dad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000102908f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    38  XCTRunner                           0x00000001019cf8ad XCTRunner + 6317
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000104e2f92d start + 1
)
```

I've found people with similar problems, however none of them seems to have found a solution to our case:

**Result 1:**

> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47696
>
> **Solution:** Installing El Capitan and updating Xcode; we are already in El Capitan, and our Xcode is the latest version according to the
>   App Store app.

**Result 2:**

> [iOS UI Testing : Failure getting list of active applications: AX error -25205](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133484/ios-ui-testing-failure-getting-list-of-active-applications-ax-error-25205)
>
> **Solution:** None of the answers give a solution.

**Result 3:**

> [UITesting Failure getting list of active application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674710/uitesting-failure-getting-list-of-active-application)
>
> **Solution:** "Enable UI Atomation" on the device (Settings > Developer). It's already enabled in the Simulator.

My Xcode version is 7.3.1 (7D1014) and the OS X version is 10.11.4 (15E65).

Somebody knows how to solve that problem? Maybe updating El Capitan to the latest version?

Comment: Try Xcode 8? Or maybe go back the other way? My experience is that UI testing has been pretty much broken in Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: So is it better in Xcode 8?

Comment: It's a whole lot better for me, but YMMV. That's why I suggest you at least try it.

Comment: The Xcode 8 download didn't worked, however we downgraded to Xcode 7.3.0 and it's working now :)

Comment: Wow! Well, that's useful information. You should answer your own question (and in 48 hours you can accept your own answer). — I'm curious about why Xcode 8 didn't work. If this is a bug introduced in 7.3.1 and still present in 8, you should definitely file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: The problem is not the bug being present in Xcode 8; the problem was that I was unable to uncompress the Xcode 8 file. Downloaded it twice, and in both situations I couldn't uncompress it. Tried with the OS X utility and with the Unarchiver.

Comment: Helps to read the release notes: "Expanding Xcode beta’s .xip requires macOS version 10.11.5 or later. Attempting to expand the archive on earlier versions of macOS will result in an error" Why are you hanging back at 10.11.4? At this point, in fact, you should be at 10.11.6.

Comment: I just had problems with an Xcode update, so I think I was a bit afraid of Apple updates :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to matt I could find a solution. It seems to be a bug with Xcode 7.3.1. Downgrading to Xcode 7.3.0 solved the problem.

**EDIT:**
In case anyone is looking for Xcode 7.3.0 for download, you can find it here:
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 1):

```
[Mobile_iOSUITests.LoginViewControllerUITest testLoginComSucesso]
```

appeared to be the real cause. Are you sure if you're invoking correct method as there is a typo in the method name **testLoginComSucesso**?

Exception is thrown because of following

```
[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
```

It appears as if your's **LoginViewControllerUITest** does not recognised the method

Comment: Considering that I called that test directly throw Xcode (pressing its little ball in the left) and that these instructions were inside that method, I'm sure that this is not the cause. Further, the exception is for that call: `[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]`; which I suppose is being called due to the AX error.

Comment: can you post your testLoginComSuccesso implementation?